Why does spanning of monitor not work for RDP?
First time setting multi monitor on my RDP, running Windows 10 Pro on my own laptop.
I followed tutorials online, using the following RDP file but have no success, RDP still only displaying on one monitor.
I tried turning on and off span monitors:i: and use different combinations and arrangement of 0, 3, 4 for selectedmonitors:s:, none works.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

screen mode id:i:2
use multimon:i:1
span monitors:i:1
selectedmonitors:s:3,4
desktopwidth:i:1920
desktopheight:i:1080
session bpp:i:32
winposstr:s:0,1,5,67,1958,1067
compression:i:1
keyboardhook:i:2
audiocapturemode:i:0
videoplaybackmode:i:1
connection type:i:7
networkautodetect:i:1
bandwidthautodetect:i:1
displayconnectionbar:i:1
enableworkspacereconnect:i:0
disable wallpaper:i:0
allow font smoothing:i:0
allow desktop composition:i:0
disable full window drag:i:1
disable menu anims:i:1
disable themes:i:0
disable cursor setting:i:0
bitmapcachepersistenable:i:1
full address:s:xxxxxxxxx
audiomode:i:0
redirectprinters:i:1
redirectcomports:i:0
redirectsmartcards:i:1
redirectwebauthn:i:1
redirectclipboard:i:1
redirectposdevices:i:0
autoreconnection enabled:i:1
authentication level:i:2
prompt for credentials:i:0
negotiate security layer:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:0
alternate shell:s:
shell working directory:s:
gatewayhostname:s:
gatewayusagemethod:i:4
gatewaycredentialssource:i:4
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:0
promptcredentialonce:i:0
gatewaybrokeringtype:i:0
use redirection server name:i:0
rdgiskdcproxy:i:0
kdcproxyname:s:
enablerdsaadauth:i:0
drivestoredirect:s:


In the connection settings, check the box

use all my monitors for remote connection

